# How to open Visual Studio Code from CLI on GIT (Source Control) View?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

We love how VS Code lists all changed files in the "Changes" section of the source control view.

How can I open VS Code and have this view by default without asking the users to click on the source control view?

- Is there a secret CLI Command?
- Would it be possible to create an extension to add a CLI command?
- is there a setting which allows to open a certain workspace always on the source control view by default?

[image]